# TinyMCE first initialization not loading external font

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, tinymce

I'm working on a content management system page edit function. I have places within the content area that can be clicked and converted to TinyMCE editors and then saved back to update the page. The issue that I'm having is with loading external fonts (from fonts.com/web-fonts). I'm currently using the custom_content.css file and an @import to load the external fonts. The editors are being added on-the-fly using something like

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'editor_' + field_id);
```

So, the fonts *are* being loaded, but they will only show up for the instances *after* the first one. So, if I have 4 areas that are clickable/editable, the first instance does *not* render the external font, but each instance thereafter does. I'm assuming that the fonts aren't completely loaded at the time that the first editor is rendered.

And FYI, the fonts are already being used on the page that loads the editor, so they *should* already be cached. Any ideas on how to get around this? My next step will be try to remove/reinit the first instance of the editor, but I know it's going to cause an unwanted flicker affect to the page.

Any help would be much appreciated.